# Devise Sign Up Invalid Email or Password Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm currently testing my Devise implementation - all is working well except for my Sign Up form.

Flash message error:

> Invalid email or password.

I'm then directed to the Sign In form.

Not sure where I'm going wrong.

Sign Up form:

```
<h2>Sign Up</h2>
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), :html => {:class => 'form-vertical' }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.input :name, :autofocus => true %>
  <%= f.input :email, :required => true %>
  <%= f.input :password, :required => true %>
  <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :required => true %>
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Sign up', :class => 'button' %>
<% end %>
<% render 'devise/shared/links' %>
```

Routes:

```
authenticated :user do
    root :to => 'home#index'
  end

  devise_for :users

  resources :users

  root :to => 'home#index'

  resources :songs

  get 'home/index'

  match 'home/about', :to => 'home#about'

  match 'home/contact', :to => 'home#contact'
```

Rails Server:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-01 16:42:47 +1000
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"DxwF+dMC//5UIX5beKhzaBLjnB2xaJe7pQb/C3xNK1k=", "user"=>{"name"=>"test", "email"=>"asdfas@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'asdfas@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 2ms
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"DxwF+dMC//5UIX5beKhzaBLjnB2xaJe7pQb/C3xNK1k=", "user"=>{"name"=>"test", "email"=>"asdfas@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
  Rendered /Users/thmsmxwll/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-2.2.3/app/views/devise/shared/_links.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (7.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 104ms (Views: 19.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: My issue was solved when I restarted the server after running the migrations. For some reason, the server cached something and would not accept the credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to wrong **url** in form helper, just replace it by,

```
 <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => {:class => 'form-vertical' }) do |f| %>
```

for sign up, url need to be registration_path not session_path.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong registration path.

You are doing registration but the processing by your rails server is:

```
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
```

The above line indicates that the devise is somehow trying to create login session for the user but not the registration.

So rails is looking for row with `email" = 'asdfas@gmail.com` which is yet not there in your database because that you are registering.

Comment: Thanks for the response I just tried this but I'm still getting: Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML, as well as, the error message in my question.

Comment: ok revert back to your original code and just give the url that you are accessing for sign up.

Comment: @maximus is right. I just noticed you have url - pointing to session_path.